# Retrive the response of the software update android

Tags: android, settings, software-update

I need to write an application that allows the user to check if he needs a software update in his android phone.

is it possible to get the response of the software update in android programmatically?

Basically is the response for the last pop-up that show you if you need an update or not.

I don't know if is possible get the response of the last pop-up programmatically without the user do any of the steps?

Thanks a lot!!!